# Sort a row of a 2D array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, multidimensional-array

Say I have a 2D array in perl

```
[2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2]            # $i = 0
[5, 2, 4, 2, 1]               # $i = 1
[8, 2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5]      # $i = 2
[2, 1]                        # $i = 3
```

How can I sort one row so they remain in the same order?

such as:

```
[2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 4, 5]                  # sorted row
[8, 2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 3, 5]
[2, 1]
```

I tried an easy route to sort the $i row,

```
@array[$i] = sort(@array[$i]);
```

It does nothing to change the order of the array, my other attempts have deleted the array row all together.

Other 2D sorting questions I can find are for reordering rows/sorting columns.

I'm sure the answer is very easy.

Comment: `$array[$i] = [ sort { $a <=> $b } @{ $array[$i] } ];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, the thing you need to know is - that an array of arrays in perl, is implemented as an array of array references.

So - `$array[$i]` - is a reference to an array.

So you can simply:

```
 @{$array[$i]} = sort @{$array[$i]};
```

Although note by default, sort does alphanumeric, rather than just numeric.

So you might want:

```
 @{$array[$i]} = sort { $a <=> $b } @{$array[$i]};
```

Or if you want to do the whole lot:

```
@$_ = sort {$a<=>$b} @$_ for @array;
```

Comment: `@array = sort { ... } @array;` allows `sort` to sort the array in-place for a performance boost. Adjusted the answer to use this form.